# Write To Access Database From VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to create a form that will allow users to fill the form in, press the "Submit" button and it will place the data in a new row in an Access Database.

```
  Public Sub Inject_To_Database()
        Dim sqlConnection1 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Z.USB File Storage\Visual Studio Projects\Job Tracker 2\Job Tracker 2\Database Job Records.accdb")


        sqlConnection1.Open()

        Dim Sqlstr = "INSERT INTO `Job Records` (`Job Number`, `Job Description`, `Site`, `Type Of Work" & _
                "`, `Job Date`, `Outcome Of Job`, `Start Time`, `End Time`, `Park" & _
                "ed Time`, `Completion Time`, `Allocated Time`, `Comment Sent & _
                "`)" & _
       "VALUES (" & Form1.SQL_JobNumber.Text & "," & _
       Form1.SQL_JobDescription.Text & "," & _
       Form1.SQL_Site.Text & "," & _
       Form1.SQL_TypeOfWork.Text & "," & _
       Form1.SQL_StartDate.Text & "," & _
       Form1.SQL_JobOutcome.Text & "," & _
           Form1.SQL_StartTime.Text & "," & _
           Form1.SQL_EndDate.Text & "," & _
           Form1.SQL_ParkedTime.Text & "," & _
           Form1.SQL_CompletedTime.Text & "," & _
           Form1.SQL_CommentSent.Text & ")"

        Dim Command = New OleDbCommand(Sqlstr, sqlConnection1)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlConnection1.Close()
    End Sub
```

Above is the code I'm using, the code fails on the line `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` stating a Syntax error, but it gives me no more information.

**Update:**
Here is the string that ends up in `Sqlstr`

```
"INSERT INTO [Job Records] ([Job Number], [Job Description], [Site], [Type Of Work], [Job Date], [Outcome Of Job], [Start Time], [End Time], [Parked Time], [Completion Time], [Allocated Time], [Comment Sent], [Document Support])VALUES (123,TEST1000,Mythe,PPM,27/03/2015,Completed,07:48:37,07:48:43,00:00:00,00:00:06,TEST1000)"
```

The Syntax error is still there saying that an operand is missing from "07:48:37"

Comment: Search here for `[.net] parameterized query` and learn to use them, instead of concatenating SQL. It will avoid these kinds of hard to track down errors, and even more importantly prevent SQL injection. And when you get syntax errors in your SQL, you need to inspect the Sqlstr after it's build but before calling `ExecuteNonQuery` so that you can see the final result of all that noise that constructed it, so you can find out what's wrong. We can't do so, because we don't have your data or the content of your variables.

Comment: Sqlstr need to finish with as String

Comment: you have to close the parenthesis  after Form1.SQL_DocumentSupport.Text & ")"

Comment: Additionally, value strings need to be enclosed with quotes and datetime fields with number sign #, according to the Jet/ACE SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it, thanks for the help

Here's the code I used:

```
        If Form1.SQL_DocumentSupport.Text = Nothing Then Form1.SQL_DocumentSupport.Text = "None"

        Dim sqlConnection1 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Z.USB File Storage\Visual Studio Projects\Job Tracker 2\Job Tracker 2\Database Job Records.accdb")



        sqlConnection1.Open()

        Dim Sqlstr = "INSERT INTO [Job Records] ([Job Number], [Job Description], [Site], [Type Of Work]" & _
                ", [Job Date], [Outcome Of Job], [Start Time], [End Time], [Parked Time], " & _
                "[Completion Time], [Allocated Time], [Comment Sent], [Document Support]" & _
                ")" & _
       "VALUES (" & CInt(Form1.SQL_JobNumber.Text) & "," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_JobDescription.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_Site.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_TypeOfWork.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_StartDate.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_JobOutcome.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_StartTime.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_EndTime.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_ParkedTime.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_CompletedTime.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_AllocatedTime.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_CommentSent.Text & """," & _
"""" & Form1.SQL_DocumentSupport.Text & """)"

        'Form1.SQL_DocumentSupport.Text & _
        'VALUES (@JobNumber, @JobDescription, @Site, @TypeOfWork, @JobDate, @Outcome, @JobAttempts, @StartTime," & _
        '"@EndTime, @ParkedTime, @CompletionTime, @AllocatedTime, @CommentSent, @DocumentSupport)"

        Dim Command = New OleDbCommand(Sqlstr, sqlConnection1)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlConnection1.Close()
    End Sub
```